# Multi column unordered list

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have these 8 items in my unordered list. What I want to do is display first 4 items and wrap the next 4 to a second 'column'. Once the browser window gets smaller to a bootstrap `col-xs-12` then it should display them all in a single column.

I've tried simply applying a `'col-sm-6 col-xs-12'` classes but the gap on a large screen between the 2 columns doesn't satisfy me.

```js
angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('mainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.alertFilters = [
    { key: 'MOT Due', value: 1 },
    { key: 'Insurance Due', value: 2 },
    { key: 'Service Due', value: 3 },
    { key: 'Licence Due', value: 4 },
    { key: 'RFL Due', value: 5 },
    { key: 'Renewals Due', value: 6 },
    { key: 'Active Complaints', value: 7 },
    { key: 'Include all Customers', value: 8 }
  ];
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
          <form>
             <label class="control-label">Alert Filters</label>
             <div ng-repeat="alertFilter in vm.alertFilters" class="">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                   <input type="checkbox" name="alertsFilter" id="alertsFilter{{::$id}}" ng-value="alertFilter.value">
                   <label for="alertsFilter{{::$id}}" ng-bind="alertFilter.key" class="alertLabel"></label>
                </div>
             </div>
          </form>
       </div>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

In the example above you can see how big the gap between the columns is. I'd like the first column to end where the longest text does; just after 'Licence Due' + a few extra pixels. Something like this.

[image]

The problem starts when I resize the browser window and 'Include all Customers' gets so squashed that it drops underneath its checkbox.

[image]

Comment: Bootstrap has utility classes that might help. Do you want a site wide change or just for this component?

No gutter on your columns:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters

This will close the gap.

Then / or you could add a small gap using their spacing helper classes:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

However, this is Bootstrap 4 and I noticed you are linking to Bootstrap 3? In which case, you need to look at this section: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

Maybe this helps?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the array into two array or using angular limit directive - create two uls. It does replicate the markup - but it lets you have two uls that can then be displayed horizontally using flex and flex-direction on smaller screens and on larger screens using flex-direction - row - can show the two ul's side by side.

Run the snippet below and toggle in and out of "Full screen mode" - i have a media query that flips the flex direction on viewport size.

EDIT - I have added a toggle button that artifically toggles a class to allow the different alignments to be seen on the click of hte button.

```js
angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('mainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.columnOrientation = false;
  
  
  vm.toggleListOrientation = function() {
    vm.columnOrientation = !vm.columnOrientation;
  }
  
  vm.alertFilters = [
    { key: 'MOT Due', value: 1 },
    { key: 'Insurance Due', value: 2 },
    { key: 'Service Due', value: 3 },
    { key: 'Licence Due', value: 4 },
    { key: 'RFL Due', value: 5 },
    { key: 'Renewals Due', value: 6 },
    { key: 'Active Complaints', value: 7 },
    { key: 'Include all Customers', value: 8 }
  ];
})
```

```css
.list-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .list-wrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

  .list-wrapper.showAsRow {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

ul { 
  list-style: none; 
  margin-bottom: 0!important
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" ng-click="vm.toggleListOrientation()"> Click to toggle the lists</button>
          <form>
             <label class="control-label">Alert Filters</label>
       <div class="list-wrapper" ng-class="{'showAsRow': vm.columnOrientation}">
         <ul class="first-four">
             <li ng-repeat="alertFilter in vm.alertFilters  | limitTo:4:0" class="first-four">
              <input type="checkbox" name="alertsFilter" id="alertsFilter{{::$id}}" ng-value="alertFilter.value">
              <label for="alertsFilter{{::$id}}" ng-bind="alertFilter.key" class="alertLabel"></label>
           </li>
        </ul>

             <ul class="second-four">
             <li ng-repeat="alertFilter in vm.alertFilters  | limitTo:4:4" class="first-four">
              <input type="checkbox" name="alertsFilter" id="alertsFilter{{::$id}}" ng-value="alertFilter.value">
              <label for="alertsFilter{{::$id}}" ng-bind="alertFilter.key" class="alertLabel"></label>
           </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
          </form>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```